# Is the Fujifilm FinePix XP150 compatible with UHS-I cards?

Tags: fujifilm, sdcard, microsd

I want to upgrade the SD card that I use in my camera, but I don't know if the card that I want to buy will work in this model.

On Fujifilm Memory Cards: XP Series page http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/compatibility/card/xp/  2 days ago there were annotations that XP150 doesn't support the UHS-I bus but today that information is not present.

I would like to get a Kingston Canvas Select 32GB or 64GB one (microSD with SD adapter) but both in their specification have "UHS-I" and I do not know if the fact that the page specification listed no UHS-I support for this camera this microSD card should work in the XP150 camera. I don't need the increased speed as I just take photos, not movies so I shouldn't see any major difference.

Can someone confirm if this should work? I did write to Fujifilm about it but to this day I didn't get any reply (in terms of knowledge of sd cards I couldn't find any explanation on the net on this).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Ultra_High_Speed_(UHS)_bus), UHS-I cards are backward compatible, if the "host" doesn't know about UHS-I they work like standard cards at standard speeds.

I'm surprised that you use an adapter in a camera that is meant to be used in adverse conditions. You are adding an unnecessary point of failure. Why do you want to use microSD cards for this?

Comment: Newer devices can use older cards, but older devices can't necessarily use newer ones. It often happens that they work, but there have been incompatible changes.

Comment: The Wikipedia description says that the device must 1) recognize the card as UHS-I, and 2) tell it to set itself in that mode. Until this is done the card behaves as a standard card: "*Cards that comply with UHS [...] report this capability to the host device. Use of UHS-I requires that the host device command the card to drop from 3.3-volt to 1.8-volt operation over the I/O interface pins*"

Comment: Yeah but on the same page "Older host devices generally do not support newer card formats, and even when they might support the bus interface used by the card there are several factors that arise...."

Comment: The adverse conditions this camera was bought for is it additional durability - my brother has a hand disability and in case the camera would slip it wouldn't break like puzzles (I know it has it limits).

As for the microSD in SD adapter tbh I never thought of this as 7 years of working and no problems with the card or the adapter. Plus a microSD can always be transferred to something else :)

Tbh the current card I have is good enough for the camera but not really for anything else I have at home, I'm buying new set of cards and I thought of getting a bigger card for the XP150 in one go

Comment: I'll wait till Monday if the support will provide any reply (doubt it) and just buy the card - I'll see if it will work after I receive the card.

Comment: These days, if you walk into a store to get "some garden variety 32GB cards", the best and most economic ones will actually have a microSD in an adapter in the package. An actual 32GB full size will either be low end/old stock/questionable pedigree .... or high end, probably too high end for users that have to or prefer to treat their SD cards as use-once-and-archive media....

Answer (score 0):

On the page you link, I see "Yes" for the XPS150 in all three columns; those columns are

- SDmemoryCard*1
- SDHCmemoryCard / SDHCmemoryCard(UHS-I)*2
- SDXCmemoryCard(UHS-I)*3

and the three footnotes are

- 1 Checked with the following models : SanDisk 512MB, 1GB, 2GB.
- 2 Checked with the following models : SanDisk 4GB, 8GB,16GB,32GB.
- 3 Checked with the following models : SanDisk 64GB, 128GB.

So, while they didn't check Kingston cards, there's generally no reason they might not work.

If there was information previously that the camera didn't work, there are two likely possibilities I can think of: first, it was a mistake now corrected; or second, a firmware update fixed some problems and what didn't work before works now.

Comment: Yes if the page didn't change (sadly I do not have a screenshot of it from last week) I wouldn't probably even write here or to support (or if the support would answer me...) and just buy the card straight away. Guess I'll leave it till Monday and if there is still no support answer I'll go and buy the card (it's like 10€ so not a big risk - only minus would be for the card to lay around unusable as I don't have enough devices for it).